# Inequality : $ab^2+bc^2+cd^2+da^2 \leq 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math

I have a excercise like that: let $a;b;c \geq 0$ and $a+b+c=3$, prove: $ab^2+bc^2+ca^2 \leq 4$

We can assume $b=mid\{a;b;c\}$, then $(a-b)(b-c) \geq 0$, by that way, the problem is solved.

But I have a question: what should I do if the problem is for 4 variables, eg:

> Let $a;b;c;d \geq 0$ and $a+b+c+d=3$, prove: $ab^2+bc^2+cd^2+da^2 \leq 4$

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason to believe the inequality is true?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Interesting question, but inconclusive, depending on one's (for example my) lack of developed intuition in this area.  Absent counter example, my personal experience has been that similar conjectures, which surprised me, turned out to be provable.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore If $a,b,c,d$ are each $< 1$, then the conjecture is immediate.  If (for example) $a\leq b < 1 < c \leq d$, then the larger that $c$ and $d$ *grow*, the smaller that $a,b$ must each shrink, in compensation.  So the conjecture doesn't strike me as *off the wall*, although it certainly could be false.

Comment: So, if I change my problem to: find maximize value of $ab^2+bc^2+cd^2+da^2$, can it true?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore edge case being (perhaps) $c$ approaching $1$, $d$ approaching $2$, so $cd^2$ approaching $4$.

Comment: Nguyenthuyhangaz maybe there is no promise from my side @user2661923    yeah thats what I meant

Comment: I've check by WA, and it said (not sure) the maximize is 4. Well, but the result is "local maxima". I will try to find a counterexample.

Comment: OP I provided an elementary proof, the condition for equality, and generalized it to more than 4 variables. Please let me know if you need anything else. I'm also copying @AlbusDumbledore

Comment: @NeatMath any reason for pinging me too

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Nothing, just thought you might be interested (since I was late) even though this is a relatively easy problem. Sorry if it bothered you.

Comment: @NeatMath not at all,your proof is nice,but seeing through the other posts of the OP may not be familiar with convexity(as OP acknowledges in another post so I dont know whther your answer may be helpful, for OP

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I see. That's very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

*If $x,\,y,\,z$ are non-negative real numers satisfy $x+y+z=3,$ then*
$$xy^2+yz^2+zx^2\leqslant 4.$$
Now, suppose $b = \max \{a,\,b,\,c,\,d\}.$ From this inequality we put $x=a,\,y=b,\,z=c+d,$ we get
$$a^2(c+d)+ab^2+b(c+d)^2 \leqslant 4.$$
But
$$a^2(c+d)+ab^2+b(c+d)^2$$
$$= ab^2+bc^2+cd^2+da^2 + c(a^2+2bd)+d^2(b-c)$$
$$ \geqslant ab^2+bc^2+cd^2+da^2.$$
Therefore
$$ab^2+bc^2+cd^2+da^2 \leqslant 4.$$
The proof is completed.

Answer (score 0):

If we fix $b$ and $d$ and write $a=x, c=s-x$ where $s=3-b-d\ge 0$ then

$$f(x) = ab^2+bc^2+cd^2+da^2 = b^2 x+b(s-x)^2+d^2(s-x)+dx^2, x \in [0,s]$$
is quadratic with leading coefficient $b+d \ge 0$ so its maximum is obtained at either $x=0 (a=0) $ or $x=s (c=0)$.

Similarly if we fix $a$ and $c$, then setting either $b=0$ or $d=0$ will increase $ab^2+bc^2+cd^2+da^2$. Now WLOG we can assume $c=d=0$. Then we need to prove

$$ab^2 \le 4 \text { where } a+b=3$$

which is obvious via AM-GM:

$$\frac 14 ab^2 = a \cdot \frac b2 \cdot \frac b2 \le \left( \frac{a+\frac b2 + \frac b2}{3} \right)^3 = 1$$

**Remark 1:** We can easily generalize to: if $a_i\ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 3$ then $S=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i a_{i+1}^2 \le 4$. Note that $a_{n+1}$ is defined as $a_1$.

For any non-adjacent $a_i$, $a_j$ we can show that if we fix everything else, then $S$ obtains maximum at either $a_i=0$ or $a_j=0$ so we are left with two adjacent $a_k, a_{k+1}\ge 0$ while every other terms are zeros. Then we apply AM-GM and we are done.

**Remark 2:** It's easy to see that your inequality becomes equality if and only if $(a_1, \cdots, a_n)=(1,2,0, \cdots,0)$ or one of its cyclic permutations.